# Center align absolute positioned icon in 767px screen

Tags: html, css, frontend

The absolutely positioned icons in the two columns need stay center aligned across all resolutions. Below is the media query I tried to align the icon in mobile device. It is not accurate in any of the resolutions. How can I correct the CSS?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .contact-mode-icon {
    top: -4rem;
  }
  .contact-mode-col {
    margin-bottom: 6rem !important;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row connect-with-concierge-row">
                <div class="col contact-mode-col col-xs-12 col-md-4">
          <div class="contact-mode-icon">
            <img src="http://pwp-wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/emailicon-png.png">
          </div>
          <div class="contact-mode-content">
            <div class="icon-title">SUBMIT QUESTIONS</div>
            <div class="icon-description" style="height: 106px;"><span>Fill out this form </span>&nbsp;with your questions or requests and we'll respond ASAP (maximum one business day)</div>
                        <div class="center-xs connect-with-concierge-cta">
              <a id="btn" class="btn" role="button" target="" title="Complete Form">
                Complete Form              </a>
            </div>
                      </div>
        </div>
                <div class="col contact-mode-col col-xs-12 col-md-4">
          <div class="contact-mode-icon">
            <img src="http://pwp-wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/Call_Icon_png.png" ;="">
          </div>
          <div class="contact-mode-content">
            <div class="icon-title">TALK TO AN EXPERT</div>
            <div class="icon-description" style="height: 106px;"><span>Prefer to schedule a call? </span>&nbsp;Meet live with a member of our Gift Concierge team at a time most convenient for you</div>
                        <div class="center-xs connect-with-concierge-cta">
              <a href="#" class="btn cta-btn-purple" role="button" target="" title="Schedule a Meeting">
                  Schedule a Meeting              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
                  </div>
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
.contact-mode-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: -3rem;
  left: 9rem;
}
.contact-mode-content {
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: #A6A2A3;
  padding-top: 3rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  max-width: 342px;
}
.contact-mode-content .icon-title {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}
.contact-mode-content .icon-description {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0 1.1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.contact-mode-content .icon-description span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.contact-mode-content .btn {
  padding: 1rem;
}
.connect-with-concierge {
  margin-top: 3rem;
}
```

The image below shows misaligned icon.

[image]

Here is the [page](https://dev-packed-with-purpose.pantheonsite.io/gift-concierge-new/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your icon isn't centered properly in normal resolution - check inspector tool and see that content of the column is left aligned since you set its max width but the div remains the same size.
Now to your question: you can easily fix that with transform: translate property like this:

```
.contact-mode-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
} 
.contact-mode-content {
  #your code that you have already
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You will also need to delete that media query fix for content-mode-icon.

Comment: Thanks Karol. Are you saying that there's no need for any media query at all?

Comment: This code needs to go to general CSS. In media queries you need to delete lines that change positioning of the icon, since the code I posted will always put the icon in the center position, the screen width doesn't matter.

Comment: media query that provides the extra margin bottom is still useful tho.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working perfectly fine. Could you please give some explanation about why you used these two `left: 50%;  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`

Comment: top 0 and left 50% is the position of the top-left corner of the icon relative to the container. Transform translate is used to move the icon in the opposite direction by 50% of the icon size. Comment out that transform line and see what happens, it will be more clear after for sure :)

Comment: Thanks, this helps me do similar things myself the next time

Comment: On removing `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` I found the icon far more away from the left than just 50%,  but within the border. . I expected it to be present exactly in the middle of the column

Comment: let's assume that the icon has 100px size - without transform line it should be placed 50px lower and moved 50px to the right.

Comment: Yes, all clear now. Have a nice day!

Comment: Can one use transform-origin to accomplish the same thing?